# Flag a problem link in Careers doesn't work

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

There is an issue with the careers site that when you click on "Flag a Problem", the box appears but the submit button has no affect.

In the error console I see:

```
"Uncaught reference error: StackExchange is not defined"
```

And a 500 error when trying to fetch [this long URL](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=%2Fjobs%2Fflag%2F93853) `http://careers.stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=%2Fjobs%2Fflag%2F93853`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for letting us know - I have just pushed a fix for this so this should be working now.